# IndexOutOfBounds with array

Tags: java, android

Each time I try to run this method

```
private void resetOdds() {
    mOdds[1] = 0.10;
    mOdds[2] = 0.25;
    mOdds[3] = 0.35;
    mOdds[4] = 0.30;
}
```

I get an IndexOutOfBounds error. I don't know why, as I supply enough items in the array to change:

```
private final double[]      mOdds           = { 0.10, 0.25, 0.30, 0.35 };
```

Does anyone know why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your indexing is off by one; it should start at 0:

```
mOdds[0] = 0.10;
mOdds[1] = 0.25;
mOdds[2] = 0.35;
mOdds[3] = 0.30;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the code to this:

```
private void resetOdds() {

mOdds[0] = 0.10;
mOdds[1] = 0.25;
mOdds[2] = 0.35;
mOdds[3] = 0.30;
```

Arrays are zero based in Java.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void resetOdds() {

mOdds[0] = 0.10;
mOdds[1] = 0.25;
mOdds[2] = 0.35;
mOdds[3] = 0.30;

}
```

Start indexing by 0.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, array indices start from 0.

So to access the kth element, you need to give the array (k-1)th index.

Also, if your array size is n, it means your indices run from 0 to n-1.

Finally, this solves your problem:

```
private void resetOdds() {

mOdds[0] = 0.10;
mOdds[1] = 0.25;
mOdds[2] = 0.35;
mOdds[3] = 0.30;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are 0 based. Try:

```
private void resetOdds() {

mOdds[0] = 0.10;
mOdds[1] = 0.25;
mOdds[2] = 0.35;
mOdds[3] = 0.30;
```

Otherwise, when you go to look for the "4", since there is no 5th element, you get the error.